# Saving a local file with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3

In making a desktop app it sometimes becomes necessary to save files. I was using FileReference for this but it opens a dialog asking for a location to save the file as opposed to automatically saving in a specific directory with a specific filename.

I'm having trouble getting FileStream to working correctly. I've reproduced this in a small example

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray; 
        import flash.filesystem.*;
        public class example extends MovieClip
        {
            public function example()
            {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseclick);

            }
            public function mouseclick(event:Event):void
            {
            var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.txt");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes("text");
            stream.close();
            }
        }
}
```

The mouseclick event is likely necessary - it was with FileReference anyway.
I am compiling with the flex compiler amxmlc

```
amxmlc -static-link-runtine-shared-libraries example.as
```

I've tried running directly from flash player as well as creating a standalone executable and through ran it through flash player and a browser. I see no new files in the windows documents directory - how can this be changed?

Comment: It works! I compiled from Flash Professional 5.5. I can't find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need "User Interaction" with `File` class, as it was indeed needed for `FileReference`.

You have to compile your code as an AIR application, using the AIR SDK and then install it on your machine. Your `SWF` file won't work directly.

Refer to these resources for more information about compiling your app:

1. [Using Flex SDK](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SDKHelloWorld_1.html)
2. [Using amxmlc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=CommandLineTools_2.html)